# How-to enable auto-capitalization, punctuation, text functionality in Blackberry app text Fields?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, field, rim-4.2

I'm using RIM JDE 4.2.1

I'd like my text fields to auto-capitalize the first letter of sentences, add punctuation at the end, and reference the AutoText DB on the device.  It seems like this would/should be a Field type in the API but either I'm missing it or it's just not there.

For reference, the API is located here: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
net.rim.device.api.ui.component.AutoTextEditField
```

Comment: Excellent.  For reference, the link to that is: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoTextEditField.html